# Control the z scale of instances with empty

Tags: geometry-nodes

Can someone please help.  I tried everything I could think of. I need the cubes scaled up the closer they are to the empty (the exact opposite of this). What am I missing? Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most intuitive way is to pop in a *Map Range* node, inverting the influence, and clamping it, so out-of-range distances don't produce negative scales...

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... and here it is :) +1

Comment: @vklidu Ooops sorry.. yours wasn't showing up when I posted :)

Comment: No problem, your Map Range is much handy :) Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, until someone smarter ...

[image]